# jsp session updating numbers

Tags: java, html, jsp

i am having trouble updating the numbers in other words, if the first numbers are 8 and 13 and somebody submits a 21, then the next time someone loads the page the numbers will be 13 and 21. i know something wrong with my sessions but don't know what

```java
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%><%@
import="java.util.*"%><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MAIN</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
   String sum = (String) session.getAttribute("sum");
    if (sum==null) {
            sum = "0";
            session.setAttribute("sum",sum);
    }
    int isum = Integer.parseInt(sum);
    String fib1= (String) session.getAttribute("fib1");
    fib1 = "8";
    session.setAttribute("fib1",fib1);
    int ifib1 = Integer.parseInt(fib1);
    String fib2= (String) session.getAttribute("fib2");
    fib2 = "13";
    int ifib2 = Integer.parseInt(fib2);
    isum=ifib1+ifib2;

    boolean numberReceived=false;
    int usum = -1;
    try{
            usum=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
            numberReceived=true;
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.out.print("error");
    }

    if (!numberReceived) {
            out.print("You need to enter a value");
    } else {
            if (usum==isum) {
                    out.print("correct");
                   ifib1+=5;
            } else {
                    out.print("incorrect");
            }
    }
   session.setAttribute("fib1",""+ifib1);

   %>


  <input type="button" value="go" onclick="doTheGObutton();">
    <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
      <%=fib1%> + <%=fib2%> = <input type="text" name="number">
    <input type="submit" value="continue" name="submit">
    </form>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question , would you mind rephrasing it on the following lines : 1) Expected outpeut 2) What are you doing to achieve this

Comment: i want the numbers to change if the user enter the correct answer, if first question was 8+13; then the next question will be 13+21. i have tried using session.setAttribute(), but not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet for your code from the question.

```
String fib1= (String) session.getAttribute("fib1");
fib1 = "8";
session.setAttribute("fib1",fib1);
```

So lets read the code.

1. Read the value of the "f1b1" session attribute and put it in `fib1`.
2. Replace the value in `fib1` with a hard-wired constant.
3. Update the "f1b1" session attribute to the hard-wired constant.

How can that *possibly* do what you are trying to do?  Sure, later on you write a new value into the session attribute.  But that is nugatory, because the code above clobbers "fib1" as the JSP's first action.

My advice is that when you run into a problem like this, you should carefully READ the code that you have written, and THINK about whether it will do what you want / need it to do.

Comment: +1 and also, while you're thinking about what it needs to do, write a test to prove that it does.